# Error on using Regex for input pattern validation

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation, input

My problem is so simple and yet, i can't figure out what going on.

My scenario:

- Vanilla JS and HTML
- A **text input** has an onChange event for validation. Every time you press a key a **regex** analises it and if its an special char it makes the input **invalid**.
- Regex: `/[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/g`

[Codepen with example](https://codepen.io/venturapino/pen/LYJOdXq)

And the snippet below:

```js
const noSymbolsRegex = /[`!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/g;
const onChange = (event) => {
  const value = event.target.value;
  const hasError = noSymbolsRegex.test(value);
  console.log(
    `Value => ${value} \n Has forbidden symblos ? ${hasError ? "YES" : "NO"}`
  );
  if (hasError) {
    console.log("<< == hasError");
    document.querySelector("#my-test-input").dataset.valid = "false";
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#my-test-input").dataset.valid = "true";
    console.log("<< == DOES NOT haveError");
  }
};
const input = document.querySelector("#my-test-input");
input?.addEventListener("keyup", onChange);
```

```css
input[data-valid="false"] {
  background-color: red;
}

input[data-valid="true"] {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<label for="test">Test input</label>
<input name="test " type="text" id="my-test-input" data-valid="true">
```

**Expected behavior**

Every time you insert a special char the regex must test it and return if its valid.

**Actual behavior**

- Randomly, but specially if you enter many special chars and then begins to erase them, regex test the input and returns that it haven't the special chars.
- Pressing special keys like Control or Alt toggle the valid/invalid state.

I suppose the problem is the regex but i don't understand why it works only some times

Comment: Please provide an example of input that produces an issue.

Comment: Your regex reduces to this `[!-/:-@\[-_{-~]` and you don't need to match globally to validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a refactored regex, and no need for the global flag with *test()*.

***Edit***  3/10/23, using the global flag `//g`in test() and exec() JS functions sets the regex objects *`lastindex`* member to the last matched position.
Thats why the repeated runs of this regex cause it to flip flop the match
from the strings beginning, to the strings end where one matched and the other didn't.

```
const noSymbolsRegex = /[!-\/:-@\[-`{-~]/;
```

Works but your onChange event handler doesn't seem to get called on a paste from context menu.
If doing keystrokes ctrl-v works fine. But if from the context menu, doesn't get called.

Extra info  `` [!-\/:-@\[-`{-~] `` matches these 32 codepoints  `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ ``
These codepoints correspond to `[\x21-\x7e](?<![^\W_])` as well.

***Info on JS lastindex*** regex member can be founh here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex

Excerpt:

```
The lastIndex data property of a RegExp instance specifies the index at 
which to start the next match.   

This property is set only if the regular expression instance used the g flag
to indicate a global search, or the y flag to indicate a sticky search.
```

Comment: I supposed that the regex were messing the code but could you explain why yours works ?
I didn't realize about the paste command from context menu, thanks for the tip

Comment: @BuenaventuraPinoMoslero - I;m sorry I didn't look deeper into your problem. The solution is to not use the global modifier when using _rx.test()_ without knowing how that works. I've updated the post to give some explain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, problem is in regex
You can try below regex

```
/[ `!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/
```

```js
const noSymbolsRegex = /[ `!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/;
const onChange = (event) => {
  const value = event.target.value;
  const hasError = noSymbolsRegex.test(value);
  console.log(
    `Value => ${value} \n Has forbidden symblos ? ${hasError ? "YES" : "NO"}`
  );
  if (hasError) {
    console.log("<< == hasError");
    document.querySelector("#my-test-input").dataset.valid = "false";
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#my-test-input").dataset.valid = "true";
    console.log("<< == DOES NOT haveError");
  }
};
const input = document.querySelector("#my-test-input");
input?.addEventListener("keyup", onChange);
```

```css
input[data-valid="false"] {
  background-color: red;
}

input[data-valid="true"] {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<label for="test">Test input</label>
<input name="test " type="text" id="my-test-input" data-valid="true"></input>
```